# R rollapply a custom function by group

Tags: r, function, apply

I have a data like this:

```
    PERMNO  date        RET
1   42366   19650730    NA

2   42366   19650831    NA

3   42366   19650930    -0.026316

4   42366   19651029    0.243243
```

My custom function is:

```
p_value = function(x){
  pvalue =  x %>% 
  mutate(nop = ifelse(RET<0,1,2)) %>%
  group_by(nop) %>% 
  mutate(num = row_number(),nrow = n()) %>% 
  mutate(prob = ifelse(nop ==1,num/60,(nrow-num+1)/60)) %>% 
  mutate(pai = ifelse(nop == 1,
                      (prob^0.69)/(prob^0.69+(1-prob)^0.69)^(1/0.69) - ((prob-1/60)^0.69)/((prob-1/60)^0.69+(1-(prob-1/60))^0.69)^(1/0.69), 
                    (prob^0.61)/(prob^0.61+(1-prob)^0.61)^(1/0.61) - ((prob-1/60)^0.61)/((prob-1/60)^0.61+(1-(prob-1/60))^0.61)^(1/0.61)),
       value = ifelse(nop == 1, pai*(-2.25*(-RET)^0.88), pai*(RET)^0.88)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(value,na.rm=T))
  return(pvalue)
}

prospect = setDT(mret)[,value = rollapply(RET, width=60, align='right', FUN=p_value, fill=NA, na.rm=T), PERMNO]
```

Basically, I would like to compute a value based on the previous 60 obs' returns. For example, for the 61st obs, the value is computed from 1st to 60th obs, then for the 62nd obs, the value is computed from 2nd to 61st obs, and so on. So it is a rolling method with fixed windows.

I understand I can use the last code to rollapply for each stock. But what I got is

```
Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(mret), , value = rollapply(RET, width = 60,  : 
unused argument (value = rollapply(RET, width = 1, align = "right", FUN = p_value, fill = NA, na.rm = T))
```

My wanted data is like:

```
60  42366   19700630    0.139785    NA

61  42366   19700731    0.075472    Value

62  42366   19700831    0.096491    Value

63  42366   19700930    0.184       Value

64  42366   19701030    0.030405   Value
```

Any helps is very appreciated! 
Thank you!